# How to obtain the final result in this abstract algebra calculation based on ring $Z[\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to understand a paper on 2D DCT. It is [here](http://www.mirlab.org/conference_papers/International_Conference/ICASSP%201998/pdf/author/ic981906.pdf).

I know how to do basic 2D DCT and what it means. Here is a method that is a lot more efficient and makes use of *algebraic integers*. I am trying to understand what is given in section 3 of this document.

Q1: What is meant by real numbers of form in eq.5 forming a *ring* denoted as    $Z[\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}]$?

Q2: What is meant by multplication that is modulo $z^8 - 8z^4 + 20z^2 - 16z^2 + 2$?

Now what I understand is that we are doing multiplication with a polynomial rather than a real irrational number. This prevents rounding errors from propagating. However, I do not understand how to get the real number at the end.

Q3: The eq.14 says that $z \approx 2 - 2^{-5} - 2^{-7} + 2^{-11}$. How do I use this to get the final result for $s\cdot2\cdot cos(\frac{6\cdot\pi }{16})$? The result in the $Z[\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}]$ is (-2s, 0, 9s, 0, -6s, 0, s, 0)?

On the minimum if could you just answer 3, that will be most most helpful.

Many thanks.

Comment: I am an electronic engineer not very familiar with abstract algebra and am trying to learn the concepts in the paper. Any advice is most appreciated.

Comment: I think the authors meant eq (13) not eq (5).

Comment: All I know is ring some sort of set. I am still figuring out what it means here but there is no way for me to answer to Q3. That is most important.

Answer (score 1):

(3) Here's one way to compute the result for $2 \cos\left(\frac{6\cdot\pi }{16}\right)$.  Let $R = \mathbf{Z}\left[\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}\right]$.  All that really matters is that $R$ is a "vector space" over $\mathbf{Z}$ (the integers).  (The correct term is "free module," but for our purposes you can just think of it as a vector space.)  They have decided to express elements of $R$ with respect to the basis $\{1, z, z^2, \ldots, z^7\}$, what is often called a power basis.  They are recording the coefficients of these linear combinations as $8$-tuples in their table.

Let $\zeta = e^{\pi i/16} = e^{2 \pi i/32}$, which satisfies $\zeta^{32}=1$.  Then 
$$ \renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}
z = 2\cos(\pi/16) = 2\Re(\zeta) = \zeta + \overline{\zeta} = \zeta + \zeta^{-1}
$$
and in general
$$
2\cos(k\pi/16) = 2\Re(\zeta^k) = \zeta^k + \overline{\zeta}^k = \zeta^k + \zeta^{-k}
$$
The goal is to compute the numbers $\cos(k\pi/16)$ as linear combinations of $z^j$, and the observation above will allow us to do just that.

We need to compare the difference between $z^k = (\zeta + \zeta^{-1})^k$ and $\cos(k\pi/16) = \zeta^k + \zeta^{-k}$.  For $k=2$, we find
\begin{align*}
z^2 &= (\zeta + \zeta^{-1})^2 = \zeta^2 + 2 \zeta \zeta^{-1} + \zeta^{-2} = \zeta^2 + \zeta^{-2} + 2 = \cos(2\pi/16) + 2
\end{align*}
so $\cos(2\pi/16) = z^2 - 2$.  Similarly for $k = 4$, we have
\begin{align*}
z^4 &= (\zeta + \zeta^{-1})^4 = \zeta^4 + 4 \zeta^3 \zeta^{-1} + 6 \zeta^2 \zeta^{-2} + 4 \zeta \zeta^{-3} + \zeta^{-4}\\
&= \zeta^4 + \zeta^{-4} + 4 (\zeta^2 + \zeta^{-2}) + 6
\end{align*}
so $\zeta^4 + \zeta^{-4} = z^4 - 4 (\zeta^2 + \zeta^{-2}) - 6$.  Now we can apply the formula for $k=2$, which yields
$$
\zeta^4 + \zeta^{-4} = z^4 - 4 (z^2 - 2) - 6 = z^4 - 4z^2 + 2 \, .
$$

We can be more systematic about this, and use the fact that
\begin{align*}
\left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^n &= x^n + \binom{n}{1} x^{n-2} + \binom{n}{2} x^{n-4} + \cdots + \binom{n}{2} \frac{1}{x^{n-4}} + \binom{n}{1} 1 \frac{1}{x^{n-2}} + \frac{1}{x^n}\\
&= x^n + \frac{1}{x^n} + \binom{n}{1}\left(x^{n-2} + \frac{1}{x^{n-2}}\right) + \binom{n}{2}\left(x^{n-4} + \frac{1}{x^{n-4}}\right) + \cdots
\end{align*}
and then set $x = \zeta$.

So, for $k = 6$ and using our results for $k=2,4$, we have
\begin{align*}
\zeta^6 + \zeta^{-6} &= (\zeta + \zeta^{-1})^6 - 6(\zeta^4 + \zeta^{-4}) - 15 (\zeta^2 + \zeta^{-2}) - 20\\
&= z^6 - 6(z^4 - 4z^2 + 2) - 15(z^2 - 2) - 20 = z^6 - 6z^4 + 24z^2 - 12 - 15z^2 + 30 - 20\\
&= z^6 - 6z^4 + 9z^2 - 2
\end{align*}
which agrees with their table.

(2) You are probably familiar with what it means to work mod an integer.  For instance, $14 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ because $14 = 4\cdot 3 + 2$, i.e., its remainder on division by $3$ is $2$.  The integers $\mathbf{Z}$ and a polynomial ring over a field are similar in that they both have a division algorithm.  In practical terms, working mod $z^8 - 8z^4 + 20z^2 - 16z^2 + 2$ just means that whenever you perform an algebraic operation, like multiplying two polynomials, you have to then divide the result by $z^8 - 8z^4 + 20z^2 - 16z^2 + 2$ and take its remainder.  (Just like how to multiply $3$ and $5$ mod $6$, we first multiply to get $15$, then divide by $6$ and find $15 = 2 \cdot 6 + 3$, and take the remainder $3$ as our answer.)

(1) A ring is just a mathematical structure in which one can add and multiply.  More technically, we must also have a $0$ and a $1$, addition must be commutative (although multiplication need not be), and the usual distributive laws must hold.  The ring of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbf{R}$ is a good example.

In the case of this paper, multiplication is commutative, so we are actually dealing with a commutative ring.  Even more specifically, $R$ is the ring of integers of the maximal real subfield of the $32^\text{nd}$ cyclotomic field.  (These are terms from algebraic number theory.)

Comment: Thank you my teacher, while I understand your derivation of the polynomial in z for different values of k that are basically related with 2cos(k*pi/16); however it is not clear as to how I use z≈2−2^-5−2^−7+2^−11 to calculate the binary output of (-2s, 0, 9s, 0, -6s, 0, s, 0) which is what we get when we multiplied our input s with 2⋅cos(6⋅π16) where k=6. We are supposed to choose z to a desired precision (in binary) and use that in a multiplication operation to get the final output as a binary number (this is used in digital signal processing).